# .NET: ThreadStatic vs lock { }. Why ThreadStaticAttribute degrades performance?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadstatic

I've written small test program and was surprised why `lock {}` solution performs faster than lock-free but with `[ThreadStatic]` attribute over static variable.

[ThreadStatic] snippet:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static long ms_Acc;
public static void RunTest()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    int one = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 1000 * 1000; ++i) {
        ms_Acc += one;
        ms_Acc /= one;
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time taken: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
```

lock {} snippet:

```
private static long ms_Acc;
private static object ms_Lock = new object();
public static void RunTest()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    int one = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 1000 * 1000; ++i) {
        lock (ms_Lock) {
            ms_Acc += one;
            ms_Acc /= one;
        }
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time taken: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
```

On my machine first snippet takes 4.2 seconds; second - 3.2 seconds, which is 1 second faster. Without ThreadStatic and lock - 1.2 seconds.

I'm curious why `[ThreadStatic]` attribute in this simple example adds so many to program execution time?

**UPDATE**: I feel very sorry, but these results are for `DEBUG` build. For `RELEASE` one I got completely different numbers: (1.2; 2.4; 1.2). For `DEBUG` numbers were (4.2; 3.2; 1.2).

**So, for `RELEASE` build there seems to be no `[ThreadStatic]` performance penalty.**

Comment: That's not what I see on my QuadCore. If I compile Release on Any Cpu I get 0.81s for the first snippet and 4.5s for the second. The trivial case without thread safety takes 0.46s.

Comment: You are right. I switched from `Debug` to `Release` mode and got similar to yours results.

Comment: It can help to read the disassembled code to understand why you get suprising results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**For RELEASE build there seems to be almost no [ThreadStatic] performance penalty** (only slight penalty on modern CPUs).

Here comes dis-assembly code for `ms_Acc += one`; for `RELEASE` optimization is enabled:

**No** `[ThreadStatic]`, `DEBUG`:

```
00000060  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
00000063  add         dword ptr ds:[00511718h],eax
```

**No** `[ThreadStatic]`, `RELEASE`:

```
00000051  mov         eax,dword ptr [00040750h]
00000057  add         eax,dword ptr [rsp+20h]
0000005b  mov         dword ptr [00040750h],eax
```

`[ThreadStatic]`, `DEBUG`:

```
00000066  mov         edx,1 
0000006b  mov         ecx,4616E0h 
00000070  call        664F7450 
00000075  mov         edx,1 
0000007a  mov         ecx,4616E0h 
0000007f  mov         dword ptr [ebp-50h],eax 
00000082  call        664F7450 
00000087  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax+18h] 
0000008a  add         edx,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
0000008d  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-50h] 
00000090  mov         dword ptr [eax+18h],edx
```

`[ThreadStatic]`, `RELEASE`:

```
00000058  mov         edx,1 
0000005d  mov         rcx,7FF001A3F28h 
00000067  call        FFFFFFFFF6F9F740 
0000006c  mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rax 
00000071  mov         rbx,qword ptr [rsp+30h] 
00000076  mov         ebx,dword ptr [rbx+20h] 
00000079  add         ebx,dword ptr [rsp+20h] 
0000007d  mov         edx,1 
00000082  mov         rcx,7FF001A3F28h 
0000008c  call        FFFFFFFFF6F9F740 
00000091  mov         qword ptr [rsp+38h],rax 
00000096  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+38h] 
0000009b  mov         dword ptr [rax+20h],ebx
```

Comment: Seems like [ThreadStatic], DEBUG is 32bit and [ThreadStatic], RELEASE is 64bit.

Answer (score -1):

You have two lines of code that update `ms_Acc`.  In the `lock` case, you have a single lock around both of these, while in the `ThreadStatic` case, it happens once for each access to `ms_Acc`, i.e. twice for each iteration of your loop.  This is generally the benefit of using `lock`, you get to choose the granularity you want.  I am guessing that the RELEASE build optimised this difference away.

I would be interested to see if the performance becomes very similar, or identical, if you change the for loop to a single access to `ms_Acc`.

Comment: I'm not sure slowdown is because of two lines of code that update `ms_Acc`. I added `ms_Acc /= one` only because `ms_Acc += one` is insanely fast and makes it hard to measure timing. I don't think that `[ThreadStatic]` somehow synchronizes access to variable - its purpose is to avoid synchronization (because other threads "cannot see" `[ShreadStatic]` variable) and, thu,s increase performance.